# WiFi network not detected (Nexus 4)

Tags: nexus-4, 5.0-lollipop, internet

My home WiFi network is not detected at all on my Nexus 4 (lollipop). I've got no problem connecting with my laptop.

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue with my Nexus 4 after the Lollipop update.

Rebooting the phone will fix this temporarily, but only for a few hours from my experience.

So far there is only one thing that has resolved this issue for me - I replaced the stock Lollipop with Cyanogenmod, using these instructions:

http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Install_CM_for_mako